# @Autowired springboot dependency injection with @Async is not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a springboot application in which I have the below mentioned relationship between classes(services).

I faced this issue, where method in Class C is not executed asynchronously with the below mentioned dependancy. But when I comment out the `@Autowired private C c` line in Class B, and call `asyncMethod()` in class A it is executed in async. Can someone explain me why this will happen, is it kind of circular dependancy ?

There was no error or warning, simply it was not executing asynchronously as expected.

```
@Service
Class A{

  @Autowired
  private B b;

  @Autowired
  private C c;

  public void callMethod(){
   c.asyncMethod(); //expect to be async execution, but it is sync execution
  }

}

@Service
Class B{

  @Autowired
  private C c;

}

@Service
Class C{

  @Async
  public void asyncMethod(){
    //do something
  }

}
```

Comment: Set your logging to debug and you will have a message in there somewhere stating that class c will be created eagerly and will not be eligible for postprocessing. This is due to A needs both B and C and B needs C as well.